# React: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this afternoon I booted up my dissertation which I made with a React frontend and a Laravel backend. The error I got whilst running my React dev server was the following: **Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.**

[JS Console Link](https://gyazo.com/b120c2c194951bbce647411a544138bd)

Now it's a pretty hefty project so I'm pretty clueless as to where the problem might be, after some research I did come across some routing possibly being the problem but none of what I tried fixed the issue since.

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reducer from './reducers';

import App from './components/App';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import BoardView from './components/BoardView';
import ProjectView from './components/ProjectView';
import SprintView from './components/SprintView';
import ListView from './components/ListView';
import SprintChart from './components/Chart';


const store = createStore(reducer);

function requireAuthentication(nextState, replace) {
    if(!isUserAuthenticated() || !checkNewProjectStorage()) {
        console.log('nextstate', nextState);
        replace({
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
    }
}

function isUserAuthenticated() {
    var authenticated = false; 

    if(localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        authenticated = true;
    }

    return authenticated;
}

function checkNewProjectStorage() {
    var userIdStored = false;

    if(localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
        userIdStored = true;
    }

    return userIdStored;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuthentication.bind(this)}  />
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/sprints" onEnter={requireAuthentication.bind(this)} component={SprintView} />
            <Route path="/chart" onEnter={requireAuthentication.bind(this)} component={SprintChart} />
            <Route path="/board" onEnter={requireAuthentication.bind(this)} component={BoardView} />            
            <Route path="/list" onEnter={requireAuthentication.bind(this)} component={ListView} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

My App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Dropdown, Button, NavItem, Col, Card } from 'react-materialize';
import logo from '../images/scrumtastic_logo_white.png';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants';
import Toast from './Toast'
import '../App.css';
import ReactConfirmAlert, { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'userId': '',
            'email': '',
            'token': '',
            'projects': [],
            'projectId': '',
            'editingMode': false,
            'name': null,
            'newName': '',
            'description': null,
            'newDesc': '',
            'showEditingMode': -1,
            'clickedProject': null,
            'error': [],
            'newProjectBool': false
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

       let email = localStorage.getItem('email');
       let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       let userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
       this.setState({'email': email, 'token': token, 'userId': userId});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.get(BASE_URL + '/users/' + this.state.userId + '/projects')
            .then((data) => {
                let userProjects = [];
                data.data[0].projects.forEach((project) => {
                    userProjects.push(project);
                })
                this.setState({'projects': userProjects});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    renderErrors() {
        let errors = [];
        if(this.state.error.response && this.state.error.response.data.error)
        {
            let errorArray = this.state.error.response.data.error;
            let i = 0;
            for(var key in errorArray) {
                if(errorArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    errors.push(<p className="errorMessage" key={"error_" + i}>{errorArray[key][0]}</p>);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        return <div className="center-align-error">{errors}</div>
    }

    logOut() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/logout`, {
            'email': this.state.email,
        })
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.status === 200) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    localStorage.removeItem('email')
                    let t = new Toast("Succesfully logged out!", 2500)
                    t.Render(); 
                    setTimeout(() => {browserHistory.push('/signin')}, 2500)
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    renderProjects() {
        const projects = this.state.projects;
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    projects.map((project) => {
                        return (
                            <Col key={project.id} m={6} s={12}>
                                {(!this.state.editingMode && (this.state.clickedProject === null)) || (!this.state.editingMode && (this.state.clickedProject === project.id)) || (!this.state.editingMode && (this.state.clickedProject !== project.id)) || (this.state.editingMode && (this.state.clickedProject !== project.id)) ? <Card key={project.id} style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}} textClassName="grey-text text-darken-4" title={project.name} actions={[<a style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', cursor: 'pointer'}} key="Details Project" onClick={() => {this.projectView(project.id, project.name)}}>View Backlog</a>]}>
                                    <p>{project.description}</p>
                                    <a key="Delete Project" onClick={() => {this.confirm(project.id)}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#a6262c', float: 'right'}}>delete_forever</i></a>
                                    <a key="Edit Project" onClick={() => {this.editProject(project.id, project.name, project.description)}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#2633a6', float: 'right'}}>mode_edit</i></a>
                                </Card> : 
                                <Card key={project.id} style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', height: '280px'}} textClassName="grey-text text-darken-4">
                                    <form className="col s8">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="input-field col s12">
                                                <input 
                                                    className="validate"
                                                    id="name"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    onChange={event => this.setState({name:event.target.value})}
                                                />
                                                <label htmlFor="name"><b>Name:</b> {project.name}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="input-field col s12">
                                                <textarea 
                                                    className="materialize-textarea"
                                                    id="description"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    onChange={event => this.setState({description:event.target.value})}
                                                />
                                                <label htmlFor="description"><b>Description:</b> {project.description}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <a onClick={() => {this.editProject(project.id)}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#2633a6', float: 'right'}}>mode_edit</i></a>
                                </Card>}
                            </Col>     
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }

    editProject(projectId, projectName, projectDescription) {

        if(this.state.editingMode === true) {
            const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
            let newName = this.state.newName;
            let newDesc = this.state.newDesc;
            let projects = this.state.projects;

            if(this.state.name) {
                newName = this.state.name
            }

            if(this.state.description) {
                newDesc = this.state.description
            }

            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
            axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/projects/${projectId}`, {
                'name': newName,
                'description': newDesc
            })
                .then((data) => {
                    for (var i=0; i < projects.length; i++) {
                        if (projects[i].id === projectId) {
                            projects[i].name = newName;
                            projects[i].description = newDesc;
                            this.setState({'projects': projects});
                        }
                    }  
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({error});
                }) 
        } 
        else {
            this.setState({'newName': projectName, 'newDesc': projectDescription});
        }

        if(projectId) {
            this.setState({'clickedProject': projectId});
        }
        this.setState({'editingMode': !this.state.editingMode});
    }

    confirm(projectId) {
        confirmAlert({                   
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this project?',              
            confirmLabel: 'Delete',                        
            cancelLabel: 'Cancel',                           
            onConfirm: () => this.deleteProject(projectId)
          })
    }

    deleteProject(projectId) {

        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        let projects = this.state.projects;
        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.delete(BASE_URL + '/projects/' + projectId)
            .then((data) => {
                this.searchAndDeleteProjectFromState(projectId, projects);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    searchAndDeleteProjectFromState(keyName, array) {
        for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].id === keyName) {
                delete array[i]
                this.setState({'projects': array});
                let t = new Toast("Succesfully deleted project!", 2500)
                t.Render(); 
            }
        }    
    }

    projectView(projectId, projectName) {
        localStorage.setItem('projectId', projectId);
        localStorage.setItem('projectName', projectName);
        browserHistory.push('/projects');
    }

    newProject() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        let projects = this.state.projects;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/projects`, {
            'name': this.state.name,
            'description': this.state.description,
            'user_id': this.state.userId
        })
            .then((data) => {
                projects.push(data.data);
                this.setState({projects: projects});
                this.setState({newProjectBool: false});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    setNewProjectBool() {
        this.setState({newProjectBool: true})
    }

    renderNewProject() {
        return (
            <Col m={6} s={12}>
                { (!this.state.newProjectBool) ?
                <Card key="New Project" style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}} textClassName="grey-text text-darken-4" actions={[<a key="New Project" style={{cursor: 'pointer', color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}} onClick={() => this.setNewProjectBool()}>+ Make new project</a>]}>
                    <div key="New Project" style={{fontSize: '20px'}}>[Your new project will appear here]</div>
                </Card> :
                <Card key="New Project" style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', height: '280px'}} textClassName="grey-text text-darken-4">
                <form className="col s8">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <input 
                                className="validate"
                                id="name"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={event => this.setState({name:event.target.value})}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="name"><b>Project Name</b></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea 
                                className="materialize-textarea"
                                id="description"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={event => this.setState({description:event.target.value})}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="description"><b>Project Description</b></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <a onClick={() => {this.newProject()}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#2ca626', float: 'right'}}>add_box</i></a>
                </Card>
                }
            </Col>  
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="teal lighten-3">
                    <div className="nav-wrapper">
                    <a className="brand-logo" href="/"><img className="nav-logo" src={logo} alt="logo"/></a>
                        <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                            <i className="material-icons" style={{height: 'inherit', lineHeight: 'inherit', float: 'left', margin: '0 30px 0 0', width: '2px'}}>perm_identity</i>
                            <Dropdown trigger={
                                <Button style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.email}</Button>
                                }>
                                <NavItem onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}><i className="material-icons">input</i>Log Out</NavItem>
                                <NavItem divider />
                            </Dropdown>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s2"/>
                    <div className="col s8"> 
                        <h2 style={{color: '#26a69a'}}>Projects</h2>
                        {
                            this.renderProjects()
                        }
                        {this.renderNewProject()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s2"/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s2" />
                    <div className="col s8">
                        {this.renderErrors()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s2" />
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

If you wish to go through other components, my project is hosted on GitHub: [Dissertation Project](https://github.com/Pjai1/Scrumtastic)

Would mean the world to me if someone could help, since I need to do the presentation in 3 days.

Comment: have you checked every component and see if you are missing a import? it looks like you might be using a component but forgot to import it in some file. have you tried using chrome's stack trace to see where the error fires up?

Comment: gone through all components and I've not been able to find an unimported component, not sure how to use chrome's stack trace as the errors are coming from node modules, so don't really know how to trace from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your project and saw that on file `'/src/components/BoardView.jsx'` ([here](https://github.com/Pjai1/Scrumtastic/blob/33b9d498df418be07099f6be2001ea02544be3ee/frontend/scrumtastic/src/components/BoardView.jsx#L12)) your class name is still App. This might be the issue since there is no BoardView component to import.

Comment: That's very true thanks, I'm not sure how I overlooked this, but this did not resolve it unfortunately.

Comment: There might be a similar problem. Please check all the exports on your components.

Comment: @Pjai1 I cloned your project. I found out that there is another problem. [Here](https://github.com/Pjai1/Scrumtastic/blob/33b9d498df418be07099f6be2001ea02544be3ee/frontend/scrumtastic/src/components/SprintView.jsx#L96) there are some bunch of unintended lines. When I cleared those lines it worked without error.

Comment: Hey thanks, I did the same but still had the same error, although it seemed that my nav dropdown caused the issue: <Dropdown trigger={
                          <Button style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.email}</Button>
                          }>
                          <NavItem onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>Log Out</NavItem>
                          <NavItem divider />
                      </Dropdown>

Comment: I do remember I updated the react-materialize library yesterday which is probably why I'm having this error now, thanks for helping me look into this!

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar problem but I do the resolve it after 3 long long hours. The problem was because `react` was `16.8` and `react-dom` was `16.x`. I did update `react` and `react-do`m to the latest and the problem was gone